# Persistent iOS Footer UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

What's the best way to achieve a persistent iOS footer view? This footer view shouldn't be included in navigation animations (push/pop/etc.) Additionally, the active navigation controller resizes its content views/viewcontroller contents to account for the footer. Any examples / how to go about implementing this?

This view would behave much like a `UITabBar`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iOS6+, make your root view controller a view that has a container view which is actually where your content will go, and below that include your footer.

If you want to use < iOS6, then you will need to manipulate the frame of your root view controller, and add the footer view as a subview of the window

Comment: Is there a good way to have all views adjust their frames according to account for the footer? My current hierachy is designed like this: My window's rootViewController is a subclassed UINavigationController which handles all navigation (to be excluding the footer). Changed the height of the rootViewController (new height reflected) but the navigation views (scrollViews, table view, etc.) were acting as if the height wasn't changed). Can you explain the hierarchy / architecture that you are describing (navigationController with the context of the footer?)

Comment: @nmock That depends on whether or not you are using autolayout

Comment: Not using autolayout currently

Comment: Then you likely need to make sure the springs and struts of your sub views are set right to have a flexible height